# How can I change a DateTime object to remove the time part just by casting?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a property that is of type DateTime? (nullable).

Currently it is binding to a grid, and the timestamp is displaying in the grid.

Can I modify my property so it somehow ignores the timestamp similiar to `ToShortDateString` but without converting it to a string?

Comment: No, a `DateTime` contains the time component. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Specify a format string like `{0:d}`.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. You have to set the StringFormat when displaying it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter just don't want to show it.  Was looking for a quick way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the component's formater, like this example:

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Data Emissão" DataField="DT_EMIS" DataFormatString="{0:d}" ></asp:BoundField>
```

Comment: No, it's asp net. I used in GridView.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I understand.
Wow, 2 negatives? is that so hard to earn reputation here? :)
Well, whatever, the {0:d} formatter should work anyaway

Comment: OP has not mentioned that he uses ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it at the source. Do it at the grid by setting column format.

Answer (score 1):

An object of type `DateTime` is *always* a date and a time.  You cannot separate them.

You can set the time to midnight, using the `.Date` property, but that doesn't remove the time element from the variable.

This is sometimes problematic, as there *are* days in some time zones (such as Brazil) where midnight *does not exist* during the spring-forward daylight saving time transition.  Therefore, once you start ignoring the time portion of a `DateTime`, don't ever use it for anything again.  You'll have to just suspend disbelief and treat it as if the time component weren't there.

In your particular case, you should probably just pass in the `DateTime` to your grid, as a `DateTime` object, and then set a formatting property of the cell to just use the short date format (`d`).

As a side-note, if you're looking for a true date-only object in .Net, you will find it in the  [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library, where it is called `LocalDate`.  You *should* be able to bind one of those to a data grid without much difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

DateAdd and DateDiff can handle this.

```
select  getdate()
    , dateadd(d,0,datediff(d,0,getdate()))
```

The datediff function counts the number of days from 0 to today

Then dateadd adds that number of days to 0 to give you the whole number of days since 0, effectively truncating the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in code easily.

```
DateTime dt = <some_date_with_time>;
DateTime dateonly = dt.Date;
```

But it's usually better to do it at the display component if you only want to the displayed content to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just change the property so that it only returns the date part.  E.g.

Instead of:

```
public DateTime? MyDateTime
{
    get { return _myDateTime; }
}
private DateTime? _myDateTime;
```

You could change the property to return only the date part:

```
public DateTime? MyDateTime
{
    get 
    { 
        if (_myDateTime == null) return null;
        return _myDateTime.Value.Date; 
    }
}
private DateTime? _myDateTime;
```

Or even add a new property with only the date part:

```
public DateTime? MyDateTime
{
    get { return _myDateTime; }
}
private DateTime? _myDateTime;

public DateTime? MyDateOnly
{
    get 
    { 
        if (MyDateTime == null) return null;
        return MyDateTime.Value.Date; 
    }
}
```

Comment: As long as you are using a `DateTime` for the return type, it will still contain a time.  It just sets the time to midnight.  It doesn't remove it.